# App metrics meter five and fifteen and day not tracking

Tags: python, metrics

I have this code:

```
from initializer import leads
from initializer import subscriptions

for i in range(1,100):
    leads.notify(1.0)
    leads.notify(2.0)
    leads.notify(3.0)

print(leads.get())

subscriptions.notify(10)
subscriptions.notify(1)

print(subscriptions.get())
```

and this is my initializer:

```
from appmetrics import metrics

leads = metrics.new_meter("Leads")
subscriptions = metrics.new_meter("Subscriptions")
```

these are my results:

```
/Users/jwan/appmetrics_test/venv/bin/python /Users/jwan/appmetrics_test/app_metrics.py
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 594.0, 'mean': 487270.99080774497, 'one': 0.0, 'five': 0.0, 'fifteen': 0.0, 'day': 0.0}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 11, 'mean': 8526.583625947145, 'one': 0.0, 'five': 0.0, 'fifteen': 0.0, 'day': 0.0}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
from initializer import leads
from initializer import subscriptions
import time

for i in range(1,100):
    leads.notify(1.0)
    leads.notify(2.0)
    time.sleep(2)
    leads.notify(3.0)
    print(leads.get())

subscriptions.notify(10)
subscriptions.notify(1)

print(subscriptions.get())
```

I had to sleep... or at least have some delay.

my output:

```
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 534.0, 'mean': 2.9940160712677093, 'one': 3.5418168192813573, 'five': 3.223746548836166, 'fifteen': 3.086436285952641, 'day': 3.0009714349674517}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 540.0, 'mean': 2.9940044223758853, 'one': 3.5464688895544443, 'five': 3.2299654713785033, 'fifteen': 3.0892815069876334, 'day': 3.0010060999693247}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 546.0, 'mean': 2.994036732877035, 'one': 3.5464688895544443, 'five': 3.2299654713785033, 'fifteen': 3.0892815069876334, 'day': 3.0010060999693247}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 552.0, 'mean': 2.994037908804833, 'one': 3.5464688895544443, 'five': 3.2299654713785033, 'fifteen': 3.0892815069876334, 'day': 3.0010060999693247}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 558.0, 'mean': 2.9940253435813493, 'one': 3.550749000825661, 'five': 3.2360816041724196, 'fifteen': 3.0921109650656318, 'day': 3.001040762965179}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 564.0, 'mean': 2.9940386925610705, 'one': 3.550749000825661, 'five': 3.2360816041724196, 'fifteen': 3.0921109650656318, 'day': 3.001040762965179}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 570.0, 'mean': 2.9940720985423237, 'one': 3.550749000825661, 'five': 3.2360816041724196, 'fifteen': 3.0921109650656318, 'day': 3.001040762965179}
{'kind': 'meter', 'count': 576.0, 'mean': 2.994065714244449, 'one': 3.554686893294736, 'five': 3.2420966461830187, 'fifteen': 3.0949247475158144, 'day': 3.001075423955131}
```